# Assign variables from row from Pandas improvement

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Let at the csv be

```
name,var1,var2,var3,var4
alpha, 6,3,5,0
bravo, 1,8,3,1
charlie, 12, 6,2,7
delta, 34,2,7,2
Echo, 23,1,6,8
```

I then have two variables which I want to be able to change manually in my code, `rownameA` and `rownameB`.

```
rownameA = "alpha"
rownameB = "bravo"
```

I then want to assign variables to the values in this row. I.e. So in this case, the result would be the following.

```
varA1, varA2, varA3, varA4  = 6,3,5,0
varB1, varB2, varB3, varB4 =  1,8,3,1
```

What is an elegant way of getting here?

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you creating a DF only to make it dicts to assign values? What is the goal here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will edit my post to avoid this. I want to load a csv, then I have two variables which I give a string value which I want to manually modify (ie rownameA and rownameB). I then want to assign the values matching this row to some variables (ie varA1, varA2, varA3) so that I can call them later in my code. The calling of these variables is done quite often so for this reason and readability I want to assign these variables in the beginning.

Comment: I think for readability it'd be better not to create too many variables - if you set the "name" to index by `df.set_index('name')`, you can easily access any value from the frame with at for example `df.at['alpha', 'var2']`

Comment: What @AnnaSemjén has said is a far better method imo. Then you are keeping all your information contained with your df. Your XY here is that you shouldn't be calling on the data with these varA1,etc but rather using the built in pandas methodology for calling on data